# java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length

Tags: java

Code that reads word from file creates file with that name and writes content is it something to do with sw changes cause it worked fine till recently. Changed code and also the charset still the error

```
public class ForRwWr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader("F:\\words.txt"));
            String str;
            String fileName = "F:\\words.txt";
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset());

            for (String Ad : lines) {
                String FILENAME = "F:\\" + Ad + ".html";

                try {
                    fw = new FileWriter(FILENAME);
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                    bw.write("Orbital Science");
                    bw.write("Satellite Navigation");
                    bw.write("Satellite Navigation");
                    bw.write("Hongyan");
                } catch (IOException d) {
                    d.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    try {
                        if (bw != null)
                            bw.close();

                        if (fw != null)
                            fw.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException d) {
            d.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();

                if (fw != null)
                    fw.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

worced fine till recently but now gives the error

> java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length

changed the charset and now the error is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Wonderful         .html (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at html.ForRwWr.main(ForRwWr.java:36)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\      .html (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at html.ForRwWr.main(ForRwWr.java:36)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Wonderful and Android are the words from file till recently worced fine what it did is tooc user input and wrote it to files with the file name as the word from file funny thing technology what worced yesterday !does worc today or has bein haced

Comment: [MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 when run over twice](//stackoverflow.com/a/47920090)

Comment: What is the purpose of `reader` and `in`? You declare and initialize these variables but never use them. You also have `str` but never initialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read `F:\words.txt` twice: once with a FileReader - an old class that can only read with the default `Charset.defaultCharset()`, from the current platform.
 This is not portable, for local files.
And then with the `Files.readAllLines` as UTF-8.

My guess is:

- either that words.txt is *not* in UTF-8, and then you get a problem for non-ASCII text.

You can test this with:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName),
                 Charset.defaultCharset());
```

- or you had the words.txt converted (pasted into); before that it was ASCII, and now special characters.

However the solution would be to convert words.txt to UTF-8 (so all languages and scripts can have words in it: like façade and mañana. An editor like **NotePad++** or **JEdit** might do this.

Comment: what about portability of usage of  `Charset.defaultCharset()` ?? e.g. on a Turkish charset computer vs Chinese

Comment: @snr I wanted to express that `Charset.defaultCharset()` (or `FileReader`) is the non-portable way, depending on where the application is started. However as the application worked earlier, the most likely is that someone added words to the file, and only now with special characters.

Comment: Yes, sir, cuz of fast reading I omitted _This is not portable_. Additionally, it shouldn't be solution but it is a kinda hint to catch the solution.

Comment: changed the code with different charset, now the error is

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue stems from different character set which is other than `UTF-8`. After ensuring the read character set, set it on

```
 List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), ---character set here---);
```

It may be `ISO-8859-1` or `UTF-16`.
However, `reader` and `in` objects(object references) seem useless in your code.

And a last point, `try-catch`es at the end are exactly code duplicate!